# How to find the remaining expiration time and date of an object and google cloud bucket using gsutil command?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I had tried to find the remaining time/date of an object and the google cloud bucket from the mentioned below gsutil command but there i can see only  Time created and  Update time. please click on the below link to see the screen shot.

```
[root@INPUNPCLX323410 ~]# gsutil ls -l -L -b  gs://lokestar-us-central1/creating-pod.yaml
gs://lokestar-us-central1/creating-pod.yaml:
    Creation time:          Sun, 25 Nov 2018 08:08:02 GMT
    Update time:            Sun, 25 Nov 2018 08:08:02 GMT
    Storage class:          REGIONAL
    Content-Length:         167
    Content-Type:           application/octet-stream
    Hash (crc32c):          KXa/hg==
    Hash (md5):             0aZAtaws0WX4EEHtBN8pAQ==
    ETag:                   CI+ysrmL794CEAE=
    Generation:             1543133282998543
    Metageneration:         1
    ACL:                    [
```

[Object Lifecycle Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKar4.png)

Comment: Do you include pictures like this in your question. This prevents search engines from finding related information. Edit your question and add the contents inline.

Comment: Thanks John for the reply, could you please check the link.

Comment: Put the contents of the link in your question.

Comment: Hello John, Please check.

Comment: I just edited your question to show you how to format information. I realize that you are just getting started. When you create a new question, there is a `tool bar` that will help you format your content. For the change that I made to your content, I used the`{}` button which formats the text like source code or command line input.

Comment: Formatting questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Answer (score 1):

You only can assign a lifecycle management configuration to a entire bucket, not objects. The configuration contains a set of rules which apply to current and future objects in the bucket. So, in order to get the lifecycle of all the objects inside your bucket you can run this command:

```
gsutil lifecycle get gs://<YOUR_BUCKET>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my question here is how i  can get the expiration date/time of an object or a bucket.

Comment: You can get the expiration time of a bucket with the command above. Also, the data inside of a bucket has the same expiration date as the bucket.

Comment: Hello Alex, Thanks for the update, as shown below i have set the lifecycle of the lokestar-us-central1 bucket for one day. but as i can see all the object under the bucket lokeshtar-asia-bucket got deleted but not the bucket. it means the lifecyle set configuration is only applicable only for the bucket objects correct ? 
`[root@INPUNPCLX3234 ~]# gsutil lifecycle set lokestar-us-central1.json gs://lokeshtar-asia-bucket
[root@INPUNPCLX3234 ~]# gsutil lifecycle get gs://lokeshtar-asia-bucket/
{"rule": [{"action": {"type": "Delete"}, "condition": {"age": 1}}]} `

Comment: `cat lokestar-us-central1.json

{
  "rule":
  [
    {
      "action": {"type": "Delete"},
      "condition": {"age": 1}
    }
  ]
} '

Comment: Hello @lokesh, yes, the lifecycle managment is only applicable for objects inside of your bucket. The bucket it will not be deleted.